# SQL Server reuse aliases in subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This might sound like a dumb question - apologies, I'm new to SQL Server and I just want to confirm my understanding. 
I've got a query that is aggregating values in a table as a subquery in different ways for different columns, e.g. for a transaction on a given day, transactions in the previous month, previous 6 months, before that, after that.

I aliased the main table as `tx`, then the subquery alias as `tx1` so I could use for example:

```
tx1.TransactionDate < tx.TransactionDate
```

I created one column, copied it and amended the `WHERE` conditions.

**I assumed that the scope of an alias in the subquery is bound to that subquery, so it didn't matter that the alias was the same in each case.**

It seems to work, but then as neither the main table `tx` is altered nor the subquery tables `tx1` I wouldn't know if the scope of the alias `tx1` was bound to each subquery or if the initial `tx1` was being reused.

Am I correct in my assumption?

Query:

```
SELECT tr.transaction_value , 
       Isnull( 
       ( 
              SELECT Sum(tr1.transaction_value) 
              FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].[Transactions] tr1 
              WHERE  tr1.client_ref = tr.client_ref),0) 
and    tr1.transaction_date > tr.transaction_date ),0) AS 'Future_Transactions' ,isnull( 
( 
       SELECT sum(tr1.transaction_value) 
       FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].[Transactions] tr1 
       WHERE  tr1.client_ref = tr.client_ref),0) 
AND 
tr1.transaction_date < tr.transaction_date ),0) AS 'Prior_Transactions' FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Transactions]
```

Comment: Post code in the question. I've edited your question. Here is a related post that can help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188828/sql-table-alias-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that following script can explain you everything.

```
SELECT 1,1,GETDATE()
INSERT INTO @t ( Id, UserId, TranDate )
SELECT 2,1,GETDATE()
INSERT INTO @t ( Id, UserId, TranDate )
SELECT 3,1,GETDATE()



SELECT tx.Id/*main alias*/,
       tx1.Id /*First subquery alias*/,
       tx2.Id /*Second subquery alias*/,
       (SELECT Id FROM @t txs /*alias only in this one subquery/must be different from main if you want use main alias in it...*/ 
        WHERE txs.Id = tx.Id+2 /*here is used main value = subquery value+2*/) AS Id
FROM @t tx /*main*/
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM @t tx 
      WHERE tx.Id =  1 /*this one using subquery values + you are not able to use here main value*/ 
      ) tx1 --alias of subquery
      ON tx.Id = tx1.Id /*here is used main value = subquery value*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM @t txc /*This one must be different from main if you want use it to comparison with main*/
             WHERE txc.Id > tx.Id /*this one using subquery value > main value*/ 
             ) tx2 --alias of subquery
WHERE tx.Id = 1 AND /*Subquery alias canot reference on First subquery value*/
      tx1.Id = 1 AND/*Subquery alias*/
      tx2.Id = 2 /*Subquery alias*/
```

It means that yea, it could be reused, but only if you dont want compare main / sub, because if you reuse it and for example you try to do folowing statement in subquery `tx.Id > tx.Id` It causes that only values in subquery will be compared. In our example it causes that you dont get anything because you comaring values in same row...